# Select all date between which an object has certain properties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use dynamic properties to manage the characteristics of individuals. I have a table IndividusDynPropValues with 1 line for each individual and each property
For example:

```
ID  IndividualID    ValueString  ValueFloat      ValueDate StartDate   Prop
108 2               Outside      NULL            NULL      2018-06-17  Out Status
107 2               Male         NULL            NULL      2018-05-17  Sex
106 1               Dead         NULL            NULL      2018-08-17  Out Status
105 2               Unk          NULL            NULL      2018-04-03  Sex
104 2               Adult        NULL            NULL      2018-04-03  Status
103 1               Femal        NULL            NULL      2018-03-27  Sex
102 1               Adult        NULL            NULL      2018-03-27  Status
101 2               Egg          NULL            NULL      2018-03-25  Status
100 1               Egg          NULL            NULL      2018-03-17  Status
```

I want to view a table with all living male individuals (I. e. Sex=’Male’ and Out Status=’Adult’ and Out status <> ’Dead’) between 2 dates using only one SELECT. So in the example I want to SELECT:

```
IndividualID    BeginDate          End Date      Group
2               2018-05-17         2019-05-16    Living male individuals
```

Is that possible? How to do this?

I've tried that for the Group "All Adult":

```
SELECT IDPV1.[IndividualID]
      ,IDPV1.[StartDate] AS BeginDate
     ,GETDATE() AS EndDate
     ,IDPV1.[ValueString]
     ,'All Adult' AS [Group]
   FROM [dbo].[IndividusDynPropValues] IDPV1
   WHERE IDPV1.ValueString='Adulte'
```

But it did not work with several properties...

Comment: Well done posting all the relevant information, especially for your first post. I wish all the new posters would do so well.

Comment: Can there be multiple rows for a given individual/property pair, e.g. could an individual's `Sex` be `Unk` until an examination determines that they are `Male` at a later date? Or an `Egg` becomes an `Adult`? If so, does the most recent `StartDate` take precedence?

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach is to count the matches and use appropriate `HAVING` clause:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #IDVP1 (
    ID int,
    IndividualID int,
    ValueString varchar(50),
    StartDate date,   
    Prop varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #IDVP1 
    (ID, IndividualID, ValueString, StartDate, Prop)
VALUES
    (108, 2, 'Outside', '20180617', 'Out Status'),
    (107, 2, 'Male',    '20180517', 'Sex'),
    (106, 1, 'Dead',    '20180817', 'Out Status'),
    (105, 2, 'Unk',     '20180403', 'Sex'),
    (104, 2, 'Adult',   '20180403', 'Status'),
    (103, 1, 'Femal',   '20180327', 'Sex'),
    (102, 1, 'Adult',   '20180327', 'Status'),
    (101, 2, 'Egg',     '20180325', 'Status'),
    (100, 1, 'Egg',     '20180317', 'Status')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    IndividualID, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (Prop = 'Sex') AND (ValueString = 'Male') THEN StartDate END) AS BeginDate,
    MIN(CASE WHEN (Prop = 'Out Status') AND (ValueString = 'Dead') THEN StartDate ELSE GETDATE() END) AS EndDate,
    'Living male individuals' AS [Group]
FROM #IDVP1
GROUP BY IndividualID
HAVING 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (Prop = 'Sex') AND (ValueString = 'Male') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN (Prop = 'Status') AND (ValueString = 'Adult') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN (Prop = 'Out Status') AND (ValueString <> 'Dead') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) = 3
```

Output (based on your example data only one row matches):

```
IndividualID    BeginDate           EndDate             Group
2               17/05/2018 00:00:00 17/05/2019 11:39:42 Living male individuals
```

Comment: But when you use MIN() and MAX () you don't have the interval of time when the individual is a living male. In the example I need to have BeginDate = 2018-05-17 (the date when we know it's a male) and the EndDate need to be a GetDate() here because the individual is not dead

Comment: @ManonFredout I hope I understand you correctly. The answer is updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
ID Int,
IndividualID Int,
ValueString VarChar(10),
ValueFloat Float,
ValueDate Date,
StartDate Date,
Prop VarChar(15)
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(108,2,'Outside',NULL,NULL,'2018-06-17','Out Status'),
(107,2,'Male',NULL,NULL,'2018-05-17','Sex'),
(106,1,'Dead',NULL,NULL,'2018-08-17','Out Status'),
(105,2,'Unk',NULL,NULL,'2018-04-03','Sex'),
(104,2,'Adult',NULL,NULL,'2018-04-03','Status'),
(103,1,'Femal',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-27','Sex'),
(102,1,'Adult',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-27','Status'),
(101,2,'Egg',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-25','Status'),
(100,1,'Egg',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-17','Status')
```

CTE:

```
;With cte As
(
Select IndividualID,
      Max(Case When Prop = 'Out Status' And ValueString = 'Dead' Then 'Y' Else 'N' End) As Dead,
      Max(Case When Prop = 'Status' And ValueString <> 'Adult' Then 'Y' Else 'N' End) As Adult,
      Max(Case When Prop = 'Sex' And ValueString = 'Male' Then 'Y' Else 'N' End) As Male,
      Min(StartDate) As StartDT,
      Max(StartDate) As EndDT,
      'Living male individuals' As [Group]
From #tbl
Group By IndividualID
)
Select * From cte Where Male = 'Y' And Adult = 'Y' And Dead = 'N'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using an aggregate to get the list of IDs.

```
Create Table #tbl
(
ID Int,
IndividualID Int,
ValueString VarChar(10),
ValueFloat Float,
ValueDate Date,
StartDate Date,
Prop VarChar(15)
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(108,2,'Outside',NULL,NULL,'2018-06-17','Out Status'),
(107,2,'Male',NULL,NULL,'2018-05-17','Sex'),
(106,1,'Dead',NULL,NULL,'2018-08-17','Out Status'),
(105,2,'Unk',NULL,NULL,'2018-04-03','Sex'),
(104,2,'Adult',NULL,NULL,'2018-04-03','Status'),
(103,1,'Femal',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-27','Sex'),
(102,1,'Adult',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-27','Status'),
(101,2,'Egg',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-25','Status'),
(100,1,'Egg',NULL,NULL,'2018-03-17','Status')


Select IDPV1.IndividualID
    , MIN(STartDate) as BeginDate
    , MAX(StartDate) as EndDate
    , 'Living male individuals' as [group]
from #tbl IDPV1
where (Prop='Sex' and ValueString='Male')
    or (Prop='Status' and valuestring='Adult')
    and not exists(select 1 
                   from #tbl sub
                   where sub.IndividualID=IDPV1.IndividualID
                      and sub.Prop = 'Out Status' and sub.Prop='Dead')

group by IndividualID
having count(*)=2
```

Results:

```
IndividualID    BeginDate   EndDate     group
2               2018-04-03  2018-05-17  Living male individuals
```